# Update a column with a calculated value

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the table I use:

```
+-------------+----------+---------------------+
| sourceindex | source   | pa                  |
+-------------+----------+---------------------+
|           0 | this     | 0.13842974556609988 |
|           1 | is       | 0.26446279883384705 |
|           2 | a        | 0.26446279883384705 |
|           3 | book     | 0.13842974556609988 |
|           4 | ,        | 0.26446279883384705 |
|           5 | that     | 0.13842974556609988 |
```

I want to add a column which will be the result `log(sum(pa))/pa`.

Any suggestions on how I could do that?

Comment: Add the column and define a trigger that makes the calculation. Or better do the calculation in your select without adding a column

Comment: `log(sum(pa))/pa` will return the same value for each row, do you want to have the same value for each rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a cross join to to calculate `log(sum(pa))` and in your outer you can divide the result with each value of `pa` colum

```
update
test t
join (select
`sourceindex`, `source`, `pa` , log_sum/pa new_col
from
test 
cross join (select log(sum(pa)) log_sum
from test ) a
) t1
on (t.sourceindex= t1.sourceindex
   and t.source = t1.source
    and t.pa = t1.pa
   )
set t.new_col = t1.new_col
```

[**`Demo`**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f05ee12/1)

But its better if you switch your logic to show your calculation with select query

```
select `sourceindex`, `source`, `pa` , log_sum/pa new_col
from
test 
cross join (select log(sum(pa)) log_sum
from test ) t
```

[**`Demo`**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2bc04b/4)